# Delete Site from Google Webmaster Tool Account using Google API

Tags: google-api, google-search-console, google-apis-explorer

I am successfully able to authenticate and use google webmasters api to list all the sites available in my google webmaster tools account.

However, while attempting to delete a site I am getting below response

```
403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
```

Code Snippet:

```
Webmasters service = new Webmasters.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
            credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME_FOR_USE_IN_V3_API).build();
Webmasters.Sites.Delete request =  service.sites().delete("http://somedomain.com");
request.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself.

I had to regenerate the refresh token for my gwmt account with

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters scope.
```

one can follow this java code to generate refresh token 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/generate-oauth20-refresh-token

Read which scopes your app needs
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes